# Using Dijkstra to work out shortest route between destinations, dictionary help. (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, dijkstra

How can I add values to a dictionary like they have done here: [How to implement Dijkstra algorithm with Python (solved with all explanations) ?](http://geekly-yours.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/dijkstra-algorithm-python-example-source-code-shortest-path.html) ?

I'm trying to create a program that will work out the shortest route between destinations using Dijkstras algorithm, see code below.

It currently takes in the postcodes and returns the longitude and latitude in a list called "geocodes". I still need to somehow work out the difference between each of the geocodes and then add it to the dictionary. From there I will be able to just implement the code from the link.

If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated.

```
import urllib.request

userinput = ""
postcodes = []
geocodes = []

while userinput != ("q"):
    print ("Enter postcode, Or q to finish")
    postcode = input()
    if postcode == "q" :
        break
    postcodes.append(postcode)
    print (postcodes)

for each in postcodes:
    geocode = []
    core_string = 'http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/' + each + '.xml'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(core_string)
    html = response.read()
    ##print(type(html))
    ##print(html)
    raw_html = str(html) 
    ##print(raw_html)
    ##print(raw_html.find("lat"))
    latStartPoint = raw_html.find("<lat>")+5
    latEndPoint = raw_html.find("</lat>")-1
    lonStartPoint = raw_html.find("<lng>")+5
    lonEndPoint = raw_html.find("</lng>")-1
    lat = (raw_html[latStartPoint:latEndPoint])
    lon = (raw_html[lonStartPoint:lonEndPoint])
    geocode.append(lat)
    geocode.append(lon)
    geocodes.append(geocode)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you've built two "parallel" lists `postcodes` and `geocodes` -- where the latter's items are 2-item strings -- and you want a dict of dicts with the distances being the ultimate values, postcodes the keys at each level.

Is that correct?

Then, alas, there really isn't any shortcut... it's a quadratic loop.

```
result = {p: {} for p in postcodes}
joint_list = list(zip(postcodes, geocodes))
for i, (p, g) in enumerate(joint_list):
    g = [float(x) for x in g]
    for j in range(i+1, len(joint_list)):
        op, og = joint_list[j]
        og = [float(x) for x in og]
        dist = distance(g, og)
        result[p][op] = result[op][p] = dist
```

where of course

```
import math
def distance(g1, g2):
    return math.hypot(g1[0]-g2[0], g1[1]-g2[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.
I am getting this error however:

 g = float(g)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: @john, edited the A to fix the problem -- now it's slightly suboptimal as it repeats some work.  Better to fix earlier code changing `geocode.append(lat)` into `geocode.append(float(lat))` and ditto for `lon`, and remove the two lines in my code with the `float` calls.